# Error when setup github webhook

Tags: github, continuous-integration

I was setup github webhook to connect with github.I haved an error (i was install github plugin).

How can I avoid that error message?

[image: error]

Comment: The error is written on the first line of the image you included.  What have you tried?

Comment: You're using a browser which is sending a GET request. The github plugin requires you use a POST. Use CURL or PostMan or something to send a POST to that same URL.

Comment: I use debian10, have same problem

Answer (score 0):

The "method POST required" error message comes from [`org/jenkinsci/plugins/github/webhook/RequirePostWithGHHookPayload.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/blob/19420c0b9e2cbac3cdb85f115d3028853af2804b/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/github/webhook/RequirePostWithGHHookPayload.java#L68-L72), which is from the [Jenkins GitHub plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin).

There is no [obvious issue involving "POST required"](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27041?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%2C%20Resolved%2C%20Closed%2C%20Verified%29%20AND%20component%20%3D%20github-plugin%20AND%20text%20~%20%22POST%20required%22) in Jenkins or in the [GitHu repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/search?q=post%20required&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Double-check the configuration of that plugin, and make sure the repo isn't accessed by an account using [2FA](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/).